# Movement arrows in linguex in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, arrows, linguex

I need to draw (simple) movement arrows in `linguex` examples. I would normally use the `tree-dvips` package for that (as in the LaTeX example below) but this time I must use XeLaTeX, which is incompatible with `tree-dvips`. What is an alternative that you can recommend? Note that I do not need to use arrows more complex that what's in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. 
  ta\node{tgt}rget {} \dots {} \node{trace}t 
  \abarnodeconnect[-9pt]{trace}{tgt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. [Movement arrow in gloss](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/140142). And for an extension see also [Long-distance movement arrow in gloss](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380954). At some point I need to package this, but at the moment I don't have the time.

Comment: @AlanMunn I know that post. This question is a duplicate only if (i) the solution provided in that post for the `gb4e` environment works in exactly the same way for `linquex` under XeLaTeX and (ii) there is no simpler way of obtaining the arrow. If (i) and (ii) are true, I will delete this post.

Comment: Well `linguex` uses `cgloss4e` underneath for glosses. Try it out, and if you have problems, edit your question to show what doesn't work with `linguex` and I'll take a stab at it. (I haven't voted to close, for this reason.) As for simpler, this method isn't so hard to use.  My test document with `linguex` of the draft version of the package code works with no changes.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, it does in my file, too -- but only after changing `\setlength{\arrowht}` from the original `{0ex}` to something  >0 in `linguex`. So, now, I can either delete this whole post or keep it in order to have this discussion visible.

Comment: Don't delete it. I'll vote to close it as a duplicate and then these comments will remain.