# Movement arrows in syntax

Tags: graphics, xetex, arrows, linguistics

Can anybody recognize the package that is used to produce these cool arrows? This particular one is taken from https://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/004081 but I've seen it many times in syntax papers, with lots of variations. No idea what it is other than some other features of the papers I've seen it in seem to be working under XeLaTeX (judging by other packages that don't easily work under LaTeX).

[image]

Comment: For the arrows you can use `tikz`, [like in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617585/140456) or `tikz-cd` [as done here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617629/140456)

Comment: I will post an answer using a new package I just uploaded to CTAN. It will be available in a day or so, and then I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Many years ago I promised in a comment to turn an answer to a similar question into a package.

- [Movement arrow in gloss](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140142/2693)

Your question has spurred me on to actually make good on that promise ten years later. The `movement-arrows` package is now available on CTAN, and if you have a current year TeXLive or MikTeX it can be installed as a regular update to your distribution.  The code in the package departs substantially from the code in the answer, thanks to the `tikz-extra` suite of TikZ libraries.

The basic idea remains the same: you markup words as nodes using a `\mkword` macro and then use an `\mvarrow` command to add the arrows.  The `\mkword` macro uses `word` as the node name if provided with a single argument. If the word argument is a phrase or contains other markup (subscripts, formatting, etc.) you must provide an explicit node name using the optional argument.

The `\mvarrow` macro takes two nodes and connects them. The optional argument allows you to add the circled label using `circ=<label>`.  `circ` is a TikZ style, and so other types of labels can be created as needed.

```
\mkword[<name>]{<word>}
\mvarrow[circ=<label>]{<from-name>}{<to-name} % under arrow
\mvarrow*[circ=<label>]{<from-name>}{<to-name} % over arrow
```

Here's the example from Nevins and Weisser (a topic close to my heart!)  For compatibility with other packages, I've not used the `\automath` function of `gb4e` which allows for `_` and `^` in regular text but instead used a `\sb` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{movement-arrows}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\let\sb\textsubscript
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex This is an example.
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\sn
\ex{[ [\sb{ConjP} [ \mkword[NP1]{NP\sb{1}} [\sb{Conj'} in \mkword[NP2]{NP\sb{2}} ] ] \textsc{aux}  \mkword{V} \dots}
\mvarrow*[circ=1]{V}{NP1}
\mvarrow[red,circ=2]{V}{NP2}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of gb4e code]

For arrows with glossed examples, the gloss line needs to be preceded by the `\glossarrow` command to make the appropriate amount of space for the arrow. Arrows above the words can use an `\arrowstrut` command to add more vertical space.

Here's the same example using `linguex`. I've created a version of the `\sn` macro that adds some vertical space before the example using the over-arrow. This stops the arrow from encroaching on the previous example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{movement-arrows}
\usepackage{linguex}
\let\sb\textsubscript
\begin{document}
\ex. This is an example.

\ex.
\arrowstrut
{[ [\sb{ConjP} [ \mkword[NP1]{NP\sb{1}} [\sb{Conj'} in
   \mkword[NP2]{NP\sb{2}} ] ] \textsc{aux}  \mkword{V} \dots}
\arrow*[circ=1]{V}{NP1}
\arrow[red,circ=2]{V}{NP2}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of linguex code]

Comment: Thanks -- and congratulations! However, I can't even generate the source file from CTAN (half a day devoted to all updates, TexLive, downloads, installations, and nothing). Could you come up with a minimal working example with linguex?

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date TeX distribution? What OS are you using?  This shouldn't be very difficult, and you shouldn't need to do this via CTAN at all.

Comment: @oliver I've added a `linguex` example and removed some specifically `gb4e` code from the tree itself.  Although unless you've got lots of documents already using `linguex` I would recommend using `gb4e` instead.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Ventura and while I do see movement-arrows listed in Tex Utility packages tab as "Not installed", Tex Live Utility needs to be updated to instal it. But it keeps failing to update... Installing a new MacTex didn't help.

Comment: @oliver If you have a little time we could try to solve this [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146243/chat-between-oliver-and-alan?tab=general)

Comment: @oliver Are you using the most recent version. I pushed a bug fix to CTAN a few days ago. (I'll also update this answer, which doesn't match the current version any more.)

Comment: @oliver You can freely delete comments!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this approach could be useful

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny]
  & {} & {}\\
  A & B\ar[u, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=b}] & C\ar[d, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=a}]
  & D
  \ar[ll,"1"{pos=0.75,description,shape=circle,draw=white,double=black,double distance=0.4pt,inner sep=1pt},to path={
      -- (\tikztostart.north)
      |- (b) \tikztonodes
      -| (\tikztotarget.north)
  }] 
  \ar[l,"2"{pos=0.75,description,shape=circle,draw=white,double=black,double distance=0.4pt,inner sep=1pt},to path={
      -- (\tikztostart.south)
      |- (a) \tikztonodes
      -| (\tikztotarget.south)
  }]
\\
  && {}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but while it does look like tikz, it would seem overly too complex to serve merely as additions to sometimes complex bracketed structures in linguistics -- and yet I do see it used fairly regularly. I was thinking it *may* be something as easy to write as this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422681/movement-arrows-in-linguex-in-xelatex but available under XeLaTeX (which the one in the link seems not to be).